# Get domain user name after host site on server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, config

I have a MVC site and i want check which username open this site and based on user name, make a decision. anyway, i wrote below code and run correct and show user name correctly but when i publish MVC project to IIS in server side, I can't get username and i see IISAPPPOOL or NT AUTHORITYIUSR. I searched but i can't found anything. Even i can't find windows authentication in Authentication part of features view of my site ( I installed Windows Authentication below security below web server)

web.config:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
   <configSections>
    .
   </configSections>

      .
   </appSettings>
   <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
       <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
     </httpModules>
      </system.web>
     <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   <system.codedom>
   <compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules>
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
.
  </connectionStrings>
 <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
   <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
  </entityFramework>
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>


<identity impersonate="false" />

 </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

code:

```
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity context = 
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var domainName = context.Name;  ---> show domain/username in local and IISAPPPOOLL after host on IIS

     WindowsIdentity identity = 
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
     string domainName1= identity.Name;--> show NT AUTHORITYIUSR
```

or in other code for getting domain name in local show domain name but after host on IIS side show domain.local..

How can i get domain user name after host site on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

> Even i can't find windows authentication in Authentication part of features view of my site ( I installed Windows Authentication below security below web server)

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly re-check your server role and rule to make sure you have installed the windows authentication for your local IIS.Besides, I suggest you could try to stop the IIS service and close the IIS management console and start the  IIS service and open the IIS management console.

Secondly, I suggest you could try to disable the the anonymous authentication for your web application on IIS.Since the anonymous authentication will use the NT AUTHORITYIUSR as the user account name. If you disable it, it will use domain account as the user account type.

More details about how to modify the authentication, you could refer to below config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```